# Access VMWare running ESXi VM from network

Tags: networking, port-forwarding, vmware, centos-7, esxi

To preface this I am a Software Engineer and have so little knowledge when it comes to networking.

I have ESXi running on a VMWare VM on my CentOS 7 server. I also have the Atlassian suite running on the server.

The Atlassian suite can be hit by going to <server-ip>:<port>

The ESXi VM can be hit by going to a specific static ip-address on the servers subnet, but I would like the ESXi VM to be hit in the same way the Atlassian suite is hit <server-ip>:<port>

Example: Confluence is 192.168.1.1:8080, I'd like ESXi to be 192.168.1.1:8990

Also, the server has two separate NICs. One internal to the office and one external to the web.

Is there anyway to do this? I have tried using the Firewall Configuration to enable Masquerading and port forwarding but that did not do what I thought it would. I tried messing with iptables and that also did not do what I was thinking it should do.

Thank you,

C

Comment: ESXi isn't a service that runs on a port.  vSphere and VCenter would be services that are configured on a port. What you describe isn't possible.

Comment: I'm confused - ESXi is a Type 1 [hypervisor](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/what-is-hypervisor-type-1-2), not a Type 2, so it shouldn't be installed within a VM on a server. All OSes should have their own IP and `hostname.localdomain` that's unique to each OS, otherwise networking can't be done in a sane way.

Comment: @JW0914 Its the only solution I can make work with the hardware I have, sadly!

Comment: @LoperC You may be tied to CentOS, but if not, there may be better server OS alternatives with the functionality you need built-in, such as [TrueNAS](https://www.truenas.com/truenas-core/) _(TrueNAS is an opensource NAS centric OS that is RAM hungry [32GB would be the minimum recommended] for NAS functionality, however because its built upon BSD, jail [VM] functionality is natively supported by the OS with easy management through it's WebUI or via SSH)_

Comment: @LoperC Contemplating it further, you may be able to configure your router to forward traffic from VM `192.168.1.2:443` to `192.168.1.1:8990`, however since doing so isn't sane networking, it would likely require a router that supports an opensource router OS like OpenWrt or a router OS in a VM running upstream of the rest of the VMs _(e.g. I run Sophos UTM in an ESXi VM that provides routing and internet access to all other VMs, network devices, and downstream routers acting as smart switches)_. Have you considered using `hostname.localname` in lieu of IPs, as it's more efficient/convenient?

Answer (score 0):

There needs to be mentioned the fact that you are not supposed to log on ESXi hosts often. Also, changing these ports looks like a crutch for something. Instead one should consider using vSphere with a domain name for example.

But:

[Here is related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58368023) and
[vmware community thread](https://communities.vmware.com/t5/vSphere-Host-Client-Discussions/Change-ESXi-s-SSH-and-web-port/td-p/2254094)

Comment: Their documentation suggests logging directly into the address given on the server as of ESXi 6.7.0.

I will take a look at those links, thanks!

Comment: @LoperC ESXi VMs can be logged into as often as you want _(I run Ubuntu in one of my VMs for compiling, Sophos UTM in another, both of which I log into regularly)_ - you can change the ports for services running within the ESXi OS, but this has nothing to do with the virtual adapters assigned to each VM. AFAIK, there is no way to do what you're wanting to do because each VM is firewalled from the hypervisor OS [ESXi] for security - the only way this could be done is by determining how ESXi provides access to a VM's remote console to determine if it's loopback based, which doesn't seem likely.